# Angular reactive form value not updating on form array push

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I tried a nested form controls using formarray and it's updating the form value, if i change the existing display values. However I tried to add a form group in formarray, the content is appearing in the UI and not if form value (JSON). I have posted the code in stackblitz. Thanks in advance.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nested-forms-reactive-vvczmt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your html, if you use `<pre> {{ form.getRawValue() | json }} </pre>` instead of `<pre> {{ form.value | json }} </pre>` you will see the full object.

Comment: Thanks. Can you let me know why it works for edit and not for new value, if possible.

Comment: personally I don't know why, at least not in your case. I think the `.value` is meant to be data that is set up to be seen (there are flags like `.disable()` which will hide things in value even though you can see it in the form, and `emitEvent: false` which will prolong when value is updated) but `.getRawValue()` will show the most up to date data for all values no matter what flags are set.

Comment: http://azanebrain.github.io/news/angular-snafoo-form-value-vs-getrawvalues/

Comment: Angular documentation mentions that the `value` property is the way to get the value of the group because it excludes disabled controls in the `FormGroup`. `getRawValue()` retrives all values regardless of their disabled status.

Ref: https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#getrawvalue

Comment: @balaG - In new mode, there might not be any control which is disabled, and hence it works for new.